# FlowRouter BlazeLayout - leaving out templates

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm Using FlowRouter and in the [docs of FlowRouter BlazeLayout](https://github.com/kadirahq/blaze-layout) it says:

> Likewise you can create multiple templates and switch between each other. But when you are changing the layout, whole UI will get re-rendered again.
>
> So, it's a good idea to use a few layouts if possible.

**Question:** Since i don't get any errors in the consoles: Is it okay or 'bad practice' when i declare a layout with all my template components and per route just set those i need?

Example:

```
<template name="layout">
    {{> Template.dynamic template=nav1}}
    {{> Template.dynamic template=nav2}}
    {{> Template.dynamic template=main}}
    {{> Template.dynamic template=nav3}}
    {{> Template.dynamic template=footer}}
</template>

// routes.js
publicRoutes.route('/', {
    name: "index",
    action: function(params, queryParams) {
        BlazeLayout.render('layout', {
            nav1: "nav1",
            main: "index",
            footer: "footer"
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the only case in which your solution would be necessary would be if your template components were rendered inside of different DOM elements.

If each of the template components is rendered in the same DOM node anyway, then it seems unnecessary to specify them all, rather than just dynamically determine which template component to render using `nav: "navX"` rather than `navN: "navN"` and just having the single template componenet `{{>Template.dynamic template=nav}}`.

I do find that Flow-Router is missing some more flexible templating, or route group default template, definitions.